# Sound is not playing After Gameover Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I don't know why the sound is not playing when the game is over. I am able to play sounds on the game menu and when the game start but when the game is over the sound doesn't play.

I am sure I am making some mistake, but I am not able to find where i am doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code

```cs
public static GameManager instance;
public GameObject PlatformSpawner;
public GameObject GameTapTextPanel;
public GameObject GameIntroPanel;
public GameObject scoreManagerUI;
public bool gameStarted;

public bool gameEnd;
// Start is called before the first frame update
public Text scoreText;
public Text highScoreText;
int score = 0;
int highScore;

AudioSource audioSource;
public AudioClip[] GameMusic;

void Awake()
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Start()
{
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore");
    highScoreText.text = "Best Score : " + highScore;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (!gameStarted)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameStart();
            audioSource.clip = GameMusic[1];
            audioSource.Play();
        }
    }
}

public void GameStart()
{
    gameStarted = true;
    PlatformSpawner.SetActive(true);
    StartCoroutine(ScoreUp());    // to update the score we need to add this code;
    GameTapTextPanel.SetActive(false);
    scoreManagerUI.SetActive(true);
    GameIntroPanel.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("TwistTurnAnim");
}

public void GameOver()
{
    audioSource.clip = GameMusic[3];  //Here is the problem the sound doesn't play
    audioSource.Play();

    gameStarted = false;
    gameEnd = true;
    PlatformSpawner.SetActive(false);
    scoreManagerUI.SetActive(true);
    GameIntroPanel.SetActive(false);
    SaveHighScore();
    Invoke("ReloadLevel",1f);
    StopCoroutine(ScoreUp());
    
}

void ReloadLevel()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Game");
}

//this one is used to increase score per second of the game;
IEnumerator ScoreUp()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        score ++;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    }
}

public void IncrementScore()
{
    audioSource.PlayOneShot(GameMusic[2],0.4f);
    score += 4; //Bonus points for game
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
}


void SaveHighScore()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore"))
    {
        if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore",score);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of GameMusic[]?  And, why are you not using GameMusic[0] anywhere?

Comment: i am using an array to add an music , check out this SS below
https://imgur.com/hy4boDm

Answer (score 0):

Is the audio source part of an object that is deleted upon the Game Over condition?

The scripting API mentions that AudioSource is attached to an object.

Comment: Do you mean the previous music is deleted when the game over happens? no its not but I can see in unity when the game over happened the game over music gets attached to an audio source but it's not playing.
One more thing I would like to mention is by using "audioSource.PlayOneShot" the game over sounds play but plays very strangely its looks like both the game start and game over sounds playing at the same time.

Comment: "PlayOneShot" allows overlaying of sounds.  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html

Answer (score 0):

In your method, **GameOver**, you are calling **Invoke("ReloadLevel",1f)** which will reload the scene in 1.0 seconds.  Your **GameMusic[3]** is not playing because it doesn't have a chance to play before the scene is reloaded.

Comment: Options to solve: use `DontDestroyOnLoad` or have a "baseScene" with additively loaded game levels.